# What consumes server CPU? (HostGator)

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I've had a site on HostGator that was being maintained by somebody else for a bunch of years and now I'm taking care of it, trying to learn how to maintain it and such.

When trying to access the website, I got an error: "Error establishing a database connection"

I asked tech support what went wrong, and they told me to optimize the database (cPanel > phpMyAdmin > Select database, check all tables > Optimize and apply)

The next day, the site was down again. Apparently it was because of a bunch of bots and the site didn't have a robots.txt. So I made one:

```
User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /index.php
Disallow: /xmlrpc.com
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /comments/feed/

User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /

User-agent: Baiduspider
Disallow: /
```

(I added "bingbot" with lowercase b because that bot was accessing the site like 30 times the amount of the google bot. I searched online and Bing's bot has uppercase B... )

And the robots.txt didn't work either. Next day the site was down again.

During this time I contacted tech support a bunch of times and they all told me to optimize the database. I optimized it like 5 times a day and it still didn't work.

One dude on tech support told me to do a Plugin purge... I only have 3 plugins: NoCaptcha ReCaptcha (for comments), WP Optimize(Optimizes and clears cache. I dont remember how often exactly because I cant access the site and do not know of a way to access them without going to wp-admin) and WP RSS Retriever (for a YouTube Feed widget). I updated them all, everything seemed to be fine, and then the site went down again.

I told one of the guys I was struggling, he told me he would go in and fix it, told me he fixed an issue with plugins, and 5 minutes after he said goodbye the site went down again.

I do not know what to do.

Some notes:

-When the site is online, it averages at around 200 CPU secs. Then it has a spike that tops at 1000 and goes offline. When offline its at 50-100.

-Highest bandwidth before going offline was 60KB/min

-It uses 2GB out of 1TB of disk space

-A bunch of Russian Adult sites link to the site. As far as I know I can't prevent this.

-I upgraded from php 7.0 to php 7.4

Comment: This question appears to be off topic. We do not support shared web hosting here. You may be able to get help on our sister site [webmasters.se].

Comment: @MichaelHampton damn it's like the 4th time I was told to upload elsewhere. But it makes sense, thanks.